# Exit from cmd on error in connection to Oracle database

Tags: database, batch-file, cmd

The following code is for connecting to Oracle database through batch file by prompting for Username, password and database instance. What I want is to exit from cmd itself if any of the credentials is invalid, else it should proceed as normal.

```
@ECHO OFF
:START
set /p U="Enter Username(User ID):"
set /p P="Enter Password(Password@o1234abc):
:NEXT
set /p a="Do you want to display details of 1a?(y/n)"
ECHO "%a%"
if "%a%" == "y" sqlplus %U%/%P% @".\AB_1a.sql" 
if "%a%" == "n" goto A 
set /p id1= "Please enter ID for 1a(press 's' to SKIP):"
if "%id1%" == "s" goto A 
sqlplus %U%/%P% @".\AB_.sql" %id1%
goto A
:End
```

Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /p U="Enter Username(User ID):" 
set /p P="Enter Password(Password@o1234abc):
rem Check creds!
if "!U!" == "JoeBloggs" if "!P!" == "Pa$$w0rd" goto :CREDSOK
exit >nul

:CREDSOK
set /p a="Do you want to display details of 1a?(y/n)" 
if "%a%" == "y" sqlplus %U%/%P% @".\AB_1a.sql"  
if "%a%" == "n" goto A  
set /p id1= "Please enter ID for 1a(press 's' to SKIP):" 
if "%id1%" == "s" goto A  
sqlplus %U%/%P% @".\AB_.sql" %id1% 
goto A 
:End
```

If creds are correct it will skip the line to exit and run the rest, if either of the creds are wrong it will hit the exit line and terminate cmd.

Thanks to @jeb who suggested delayed expansion for special characters, see comment below.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its not working.Its giving the following error: "Set was unexpected at this time"  Actually I cant store anything in %actualusername% as I cannot have access to Oracle client database. Please help.

Comment: @user1458830 I have changed my answer to something much simpler, I think I understand what your trying to do now. Also, is this the complete batch file? As I can't see an `A` label and the `End` label being used anywhere? Also I have substituted your `NEXT` label as I couldn't see it being used either.

Comment: You should switch to delayed expansion, especially in `IF "!U!" == "JoeBloggs" if "!P!" == "Pass&|<>word" goto :CRDSOK` to be safe against empty input or input with special characters

Comment: @jeb Thanks for the suggestion, I haven't really used delayed expansion before, is my syntax in my edit correct?

Comment: Yes, should be working. In general, delayed expansion is much more powerful than the normal expansion

Comment: But "JoeBloggs" and "Pa$$w0rd" cannot be set as there are multiple users who are logging in with different IDs.